# Can't install my package into a separate directory

Tags: python

I have distributed my Python project using `setup.py sdisy`, and I can locate my package in my system:

```
webcluster4u@ingestion-jenkins-vm:~/google-cloud-functions$ python3 -m pip list
Package                  Version
------------------------ ----------
...
file-ingestion           0.2
```

Now when I to run the command below I get an error:

```
webcluster4u@ingestion-jenkins-vm:~/google-cloud-functions$ python3 -m pip install -t /home/webcluster4u/google-cloud-functions/com/mahdi/python/functions/gcs/dependency file-ingestion
Collecting file-ingestion
  Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement file-ingestion (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for file-ingestion
```

I am not sure what I am missing. Can anyone help me?

It is a bit strange that whenever I use the above command or use the file-ingestion in `requirement.txt`, I get the above message saying it cannot collect the package.

Comment: that first command shows you packages already installed, so is it already installed to begin with?

Comment: yes, the package is installed and I want to install it to another directory.

Comment: you need to point it to where the package resides on the computer otherwise it is searching pypi for it